# How to show default value in select option (parent_id)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I tried to save a `parent_id` of `Category` in Laravel 5.8 successfully, but I want to edit category now.

**CategoryController.php**

```php
public function edit(Category $category)
{
    return view('Admin.categories.edit', compact('category'));
}

public function update(CategoryRequest $request, Category $category)
{
    $category->update($request->all());

    return redirect(route('categories.index'));
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```php
<form action="{{ route('categories.update', $category->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @include('Admin.layouts.errors')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name') ? : $category->name  }}" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="parent_id">Sub Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="parent_id" name="parent_id" data-live-search="true">
            @foreach(\App\Category::all() as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ trim($category->id) , $category->pluck('id')->toArray() ? 'selected' : ''  }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

For example, I have the following categories in the database.

```
id          name            parent_id

1       Software        0
2       Hardware        0
3       Photoshop       1
4       CoredDraw       1
```

If a user, for example, selects CorelDraw for edit, open edit for it. Select the `name` input tag, write CorelDraw. Select the `parent_id` option tag select Software. Because this is parent_id is = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to do some basic improvement in your code, Make a practice of fire query in the model or in the controller

Blade file is not for load the data from the database

**Controller**

```
public function edit(Category $category)
{
    $allCategory = \App\Category::all();
    return view('Admin.categories.edit', compact('category','allCategory'));
}
```

**Blade**

```
<select class="form-control" id="parent_id" name="parent_id" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="">Select Parent</option> 
    @foreach($allCategory as $cate)
        <option value="{{ $cate->id }}" {{ $category->id == $cate->id ? 'selected' : ''  }}>{{ $cate->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

> Once the user starts typing different category name you need to reset the select box using any client side script